# Get data from query string in url as to use in text - Where to start

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, string

I've got a unique URL that has been generated by a gravity form on my wordpress. I want part of the data that is in the query string of that url to be displayed in an introduction on the page of that URL. For example: "Hi {username} thank you visiting this page ..."

However, I would like to use php but I have no idea what to look for or where to start.

Does anyone have some keywords, sources or even snippets that i can use?

Thanks.

Comment: Using text directly from a query string is a bad idea. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: @Ervin Retel Would you like to get &username=erwinretel part from url and print 'erwinretel'? Am I understand good? If so I will provide you a solution

Comment: If you are using a query string value on the page, make sure you escape it properly!!

Comment: Tips:  1. `strip_tags()` to remove `<script>` tags. 2. `str_replace('{xyz}',$value,$original)` to change the template text. 3. `parse_url()` to parse an url an extract its componets for later use.

Comment: Thanks all! I didnt know this. Always good to ask a question here.